# looking for a joke/humorous/cartoon data set

Tags: data-request

For a reasearch i'm doing I need a data set as sepcified in the head line. I'm already familliar with [JESTER](http://eigentaste.berkeley.edu/dataset/), and I wonder if there are any other available sets of this sort, , since i dind't find any.

I would like to have more data about the user (JESTER has only a user i.d. and jokes ratings): gender, age, location, education, etc. Also, jokes that are short and has some formula behind it, for example "you have two cows..." and unlike JESTER's jokes that are long and varied, are prefered

Comment: What meta data do you need associated with the jokes/cartoons? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen I would like to have data about the user: gender, age, location, education, etc. Also, jokes that are short and has some fomula behind it, for example "you have two cows..." and unlike JESTER's jokes that are long and varied, are prefered.

Comment: I asked you to edit your question. Comments can disappear.

Answer (score 6):

Not a super easy idea to implement, but you can use posts to sub-reddits like [/r/jokes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/). Users then have a profile of posts and comments that you can scan and categorize, and each joke has a rating (up- or down-votes) and comments.

---

You can access the data with a Reddit data dump

- [Details](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdata/comments/3aujfe/10_years_of_reddit_data_dump/)
- [Google Big Query](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512)
- [Archive.org comment corpus](https://archive.org/details/2015_reddit_comments_corpus)

---

Other subreddits

- [/r/cleanjokes](https://www.reddit.com/r/cleanjokes/)
- [/r/dirtyjokes](https://www.reddit.com/r/dirtyjokes/)
- [/r/dadjokes](https://www.reddit.com/r/dadjokes/)
- plus thousands more

I couldn't find a "joke" meta-reddit:

```
Example:  https://www.reddit.com/r/jokes+dadjokes
```